# solving a diagonalization theoretical linear algebra exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I ve been working on this exercise unsuccessfully for some time.   I hope my translation to english is clear enaugh for you to help me.

I ve solved items 1  ( -1,0, 1 are the eigenvalues )  and  2b that is trivial, but none of the rest.

Here it goes:

Let V be a (real) vector space with finite dimension and T an operator $T:V \mapsto V $ such that $T=T^{3}$ that has three eigenvalues $\lambda _1 < \lambda _2 < \lambda _3 $ with $S_{\lambda_1},S_{\lambda_2},S_{\lambda_3}$ the corresponding eigenspaces.

1. Find $\lambda _1 , \lambda _2 , \lambda _3 $
    With $v \in V$
2. Prove that     a) $\frac{1}{2}T^{2}(v) - \frac{1}{2}T(v) \in S_{\lambda_1}$     b)  $v - \frac{1}{2}T^{2}(v)  \in S_{\lambda_2}$    c) $\frac{1}{2}T^{2}(v) + \frac{1}{2}T(v) \in S_{\lambda_3}$
3. Prove that $V= S_{\lambda_1}\oplus S_{\lambda_2}\oplus S_{\lambda_3}$
4. Prove that T is diagonalizable
5. Find the possible diagonal matrixes associated with T if $dim(V)=4$

Thanks in advance

*Edit 1 :*

Thanks all for the tips
I ve solved parts 1,2,3,4  (I searched for the decomposition theorem but didn t use it )

For proving the second part just did the calculations.

For proving the direct sum, I used that for any v in V, adding the a), b) c) statements , every vector in V  is in S1+S2+S3,  as S1,S2,S3  just have the zero element in common, it has to be a direct sum.

For proving that it should then be diagonalizable operator , i used that
$dim (V) = dim (S1) + dim (S2) + dim (S3)$
So the associated eigenvalues have the algebraic multiplicity needed to split the characteristic polynomial , and then there is a diagonal matrix associated to T.

***For the last fifth part I still have some doubts....***

¿Can I say, having in $ker(T)$ vectors such as $v=T^{2}(v)$ , (as proved in prior part),  that $Kert(T)$ has  then dimension 2 at least, because $T^{2}$ "inherits" the eigenvalues 1 and 0 from T?

If so, all the possible matrices with $dim(V)= 4 $are just those having the elements 1,-1,0,0  in the main diagonal .

That makes 12 possible 4×4 matrices, if I counted them right.

Comment: For 2a) for example, when you get a $T^3,$ you just need to substitute $T$.  If this doesn't help, please show us what you are trying to do, and where you're getting stuck.  It's very hard to help you if you don't show us where you're having difficulty.

Comment: You are right, I was applying T of the left side of the equation and making it equal to -v in case of eigenvalue 1, instead of applying T on left side of the equation and making it equal to the original left side.

Comment: I am now trying to prove that this direct sum completes the space.

Comment: @anamvd, 3) is a general result known as [Primary Decomposition Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primary_Decomposition_Theorem).